# Idiomatic use of auto_ptr to transfer ownership to a container

Tags: c++

I'm refreshing my C++ knowledge after not having used it in anger for a number of years.  In writing some code to implement some data structure for practice, I wanted to make sure that my code was exception safe.  So I've tried to use `std::auto_ptr`s in what I think is an appropriate way.  Simplifying somewhat, this is what I have:

```
class Tree
{
public:
    ~Tree() { /* delete all Node*s in the tree */ }
    void insert(const string& to_insert);
    ...

private:
    struct Node {
        ...
        vector<Node*> m_children;
    };

    Node* m_root;
};

template<T>
void push_back(vector<T*>& v, auto_ptr<T> x)
{
    v.push_back(x.get());
    x.release();
}

void Tree::insert(const string& to_insert)
{
    Node* n = ...;  // find where to insert the new node
    ...
    push_back(n->m_children, auto_ptr<Node>(new Node(to_insert));
    ...
}
```

So I'm wrapping the function that would put the pointer into the container, `vector::push_back`, and relying on the by-value `auto_ptr` argument to
ensure that the `Node*` is deleted if the `vector` resize fails.

Is this an idiomatic use of `auto_ptr` to save a bit of boilerplate in my
`Tree::insert`?  Any improvements you can suggest?  Otherwise I'd have to have
something like:

```
Node* n = ...;  // find where to insert the new node
auto_ptr<Node> new_node(new Node(to_insert));
n->m_children.push_back(new_node.get());
new_node.release();
```

which kind of clutters up what would have been a single line of code if I wasn't
worrying about exception safety and a memory leak.

(Actually I was wondering if I could post my whole code sample (about 300 lines) and ask people to critique it for idiomatic C++ usage in general, but I'm not sure whether that kind of question is appropriate on stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not idiomatic to write your own container: it is rather exceptional, and for the most part useful only for learning how to write containers. At any rate, it is most certainly not idiomatic to use `std::autp_ptr` with standard containers. In fact, it's wrong, because copies of `std::auto_ptr` aren't equivalent: only one `auto_ptr` owns a pointee at any given time.

As for idiomatic use of `std::auto_ptr`, you should always name your `auto_ptr` on construction:

```
int wtv() { /* ... */ }
void trp(std::auto_ptr<int> p, int i) { /* ... */ }

void safe() {
    std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int(12));
    trp(p, wtv());
}

void danger() {
    trp(std::auto_ptr<int>(new int(12)), wtv());
}
```

Because the C++ standard allows arguments to evaluate in any arbitrary order, the call to `danger()` is unsafe. In the call to `trp()` in `danger()`, the compiler may allocate the integer, then create the `auto_ptr`, and finally call `wtv()`. Or, the compiler may allocate a new integer, call `wtv()`, and finally create the `auto_ptr`. If `wtv()` throws an exception then `danger()` may or may not leak.

In the case of `safe()`, however, because the `auto_ptr` is constructed a-priori, RAII guarantees it will clean up properly whether or not `wtv()` throws an exception.

Comment: Re writing your own containers, sure, I would normally look for an existing implementation. (In this case the real data structure I was writing was a Patricia.) But as mentioned, writing this was more for practice than anything practical.  I'm aware of the impossibility of using auto_ptrs in STL containers.

The point about order of argument evaluation is a good one!  In my case I should be OK since the other argument is just a member lookup, but I guess it would be good to be consistent and always name my auto_ptrs to avoid this potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

For example, see the interface of the Boost.Pointer Container library. The various pointer containers all feature an insert function taking an `auto_ptr` which semantically guarantees that they take ownership (they also have the raw pointer version but hey :p).

There are however other ways to achieve what you're doing with regards to exception safety because it's only internal here. To understand it, you need to understand what could go wrong (ie throw) and then reorder your instructions so that the operations that may throw are done with before the side-effects occur.

For example, taking from your post:

```
auto_ptr<Node> new_node(new Node(to_insert)); // 1
n->m_children.push_back(new_node.get());      // 2
new_node.release();                           // 3
```

Let's check each line,

1. The constructor may throw (for example if the CopyConstructor of the type throws), in this case however you are guaranteed that `new` will perform the cleanup for you
2. The call to `push_back` may throw a `std::bad_alloc` if the memory is exhausted. That's the only error possible as copying a pointer is a no-throw operation
3. This is guaranteed not to throw

If you look closely, you'll remark that you would not have to worry if you could somehow have 2 being executed before 1. It is in fact possible:

```
n->m_children.reserve(n->m_children.size() + 1);
n->m_children.push_back(new Node(to_insert));
```

The call to `reserve` may throw (`bad_alloc`), but if it completes normally you are then guaranteed that no reallocation will occur until `size` becomes equal to `capacity` and you try another insertion.

The call to `new` may fall if the constructor throw, in which case `new` will perform the cleanup, if it completes you're left with a pointer that is immediately inserted in the `vector`... which is guaranteed not to throw because of the line above.

Thus, the use of `auto_ptr` may be replaced here. It was nonetheless a good idea, though as has been noted you should refrain from executing RAII initialization within a function evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about using `reserve` to avoid the `auto_ptr`.  I did in fact have that in my code before I switched to using the `auto_ptr`, because I thought it'd be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of declaring the ownership of pointer.  This is one of the great features in c++0x, `std::unique_ptr`s.  However `std::auto_ptr` is so hard to understand and lethal is even slightly misued I would suggest avoiding it entirely.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm

Comment: He is not suggesting you put auto_ptr's in a std container

Comment: I saw that after posting, hence the edit.  Figured the link might be useful anyway.